# How can I mock data for unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to create an elegant way to write dummy data for my tests without copy pasting.

```
public void AssetIndexPortfolioCompositionMappingTest()
{
    var AssetIndexDTO = new AssetIndexSummaryDto()
    {
        PortfolioComposition = new PortfolioCompositionDto()
        {
            FaceValue = decimal.Zero,
            InsolvencyCasesPercentage = 1,
            LegalCasesPercentage = 2,
            NumberOfAccounts = 3,
            NumberOfCustomers = 4,
            NumberOfTotalPayments = 5,
            Principal = 6.7m
        }
    };
            
    var AssetIndexEntity = new AssetIndexEntity();

    _mapper.Map(AssetIndexDTO, AssetIndexEntity);
    // Assert

    AssetIndexDTO.PortfolioComposition.FaceValue.Should().Be(AssetIndexEntity.FaceValue);
    AssetIndexDTO.PortfolioComposition.LegalCasesPercentage.Should().Be(AssetIndexEntity.LegalCasesPercentage);
    AssetIndexDTO.PortfolioComposition.NumberOfAccounts.Should().Be(AssetIndexEntity.NumberOfAccounts);
    AssetIndexDTO.PortfolioComposition.NumberOfCustomers.Should().Be(AssetIndexEntity.NumberOfCustomers);
    AssetIndexDTO.PortfolioComposition.NumberOfTotalPayments.Should().Be(AssetIndexEntity.NumberOfTotalPayments);
    AssetIndexDTO.PortfolioComposition.Principal.Should().Be(AssetIndexEntity.Principal);
}
```

Here is my test and the part where I initialize a new object of AssetIndexDTO, I want to mock it so I can re use it in all my tests without copy pasting it every time

What I tried is using moq

```
var mock = new Mock<AssetIndexSummaryDto>();
mock.SetupAllProperties();
```

and then in assert I am trying to compare it to the mapped value

```
mock.Object.PortfolioComposition.FaceValue.Should().Be(AssetIndexEntity.FaceValue);
```

but it isnt working and throwing an error of `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't generally mock data, you mock functionality that is not relevant/necessary for tests.

Just move the code that generates the dummy data to a method and call in all of your tests:

```
public void AssetIndexPortfolioCompositionMappingTest()
{
    var AssetIndexDTO = GetTestAssetIndexSummaryDto();
    var AssetIndexEntity = new AssetIndexEntity();
    _mapper.Map(AssetIndexDTO, AssetIndexEntity);
    
    // Assert
    AssetIndexDTO.PortfolioComposition.FaceValue.Should().Be(AssetIndexEntity.FaceValue);
    AssetIndexDTO.PortfolioComposition.LegalCasesPercentage.Should().Be(AssetIndexEntity.LegalCasesPercentage);
    AssetIndexDTO.PortfolioComposition.NumberOfAccounts.Should().Be(AssetIndexEntity.NumberOfAccounts);
    AssetIndexDTO.PortfolioComposition.NumberOfCustomers.Should().Be(AssetIndexEntity.NumberOfCustomers);
    AssetIndexDTO.PortfolioComposition.NumberOfTotalPayments.Should().Be(AssetIndexEntity.NumberOfTotalPayments);
    AssetIndexDTO.PortfolioComposition.Principal.Should().Be(AssetIndexEntity.Principal);
}

private AssetIndexSummaryDto GetTestAssetIndexSummaryDto()
{
    return new AssetIndexSummaryDto()
    {
        PortfolioComposition = new PortfolioCompositionDto()
        {
            FaceValue = decimal.Zero,
            InsolvencyCasesPercentage = 1,
            LegalCasesPercentage = 2,
            NumberOfAccounts = 3,
            NumberOfCustomers = 4,
            NumberOfTotalPayments = 5,
            Principal = 6.7m
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid copy-pasting, I suggest you to implement some method that creates that object. And reuse that method in your tests. I do not see the need of mocking here.

Comment: How would I do that? I cant find anything about this on the internet, all of the suggestions are for Autofixer or Bogus and other libraries

Comment: You don't find it because it is a very basic concept. You may want a Factory method or class or maybe even a Pool ... this could be done in many different ways but most of it is up to you.

Comment: But in fact, if you want to test the mapper, then Bogus or something equivalent may be the thing you want, not a mocker.